# How to log request channel into a log file?

Tags: symfony, logging, monolog

I am currently running a Symfony 5 project in dev environment.

I would like to output requests logs (like `10:01:39 request.INFO Matched route "login_route"`) into a file.

I have the following `config/packages/dev/monolog.yaml` file:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            channels: [event]
```

With the YAML above, it logs correctly into the file `/tmp/dev-logs/dev.log` when I execute `bin/console cache:clear`.

But, it does not log anything when I perform requests on the application, no matter if I set `channels: [request]` or `channels: ~` or even no `channel` param at all.

How can I edit the settings of that `monolog.yaml` file in order to log request channel logs ?

Answer (score -1):

I have found the answer! This is very specific to my configuration.

In fact, I have two Docker containers (that both mount the project directory as a volume) for development:

- one for code edition (with a linter, syntax checker, specific vim configuration...etc...)
- one to access the application through HTTP using PHP-FPM (the one that is used when I make HTTP requests on the app)

So, when I perform a `bin/console cache:clear` from the first container I use for development, it logs into the `/tmp/dev-logs/dev.log` file of that first container; but when I execute HTTP requests, it logs into the `/tmp/dev-logs/dev.log` file of that second container;

I was checking the first container file only while it was logging into the second container file instead. So, I was simply not checking the right file.

Everything works. :)